# -bash: !/usr/bin/env: event not found

Tags: python, linux, bash, macos, echo

I got this strange error message trying to write shebang to a python script:

```
$ echo "#!/usr/bin/env python" > scripts/sandbox.py 
-bash: !/usr/bin/env: event not found

$ echo "say what?" > scripts/sandbox.py
```

Immediately doing the same thing but without using shebang line works. What is this behavior and how can it be overcome?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`!` is a special character to bash, it is used to refer to previous commands. It is expanded within double-quotes.
To avoid that, enclose them in single-quotes instead:

```
echo '#!/usr/bin/env python' > scripts/sandbox.py
```

[@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) clarified it beautifully in a comment:

> More specifically, `!` is special to Bash's history expansion feature, which is on by default (only) in interactive shells. In addition to avoiding it by using single-quoted strings, it can be turned off altogether with `set +H`

Comment: More specifically, `!` is special to Bash's _history expansion_ feature, which is on by default (only) in interactive shells. In addition to avoiding it by using single-quoted strings, it can be turned off altogether with `set +H`.